# Powershell - Using Invoke-RestMethod, unable to extract "Status" data

Tags: xml, powershell, invoke-restmethod

I'm a newbie when it comes to using soap and rest, so don't assume I know what I'm doing. I've been doing some google searching and have confused myself more that I've helped.

I'm unable to extract the "Status" of connecting to a site using "Invoke-RestMethod" in PowerShell.  When I use the "outerxml" option, I'm able to pull back all of the data that's returned (look at the attached file), but I'm unable to extract only the "Status", which is what I need.

I'm using code that I extracted from Postman to connect to the site, which works, but I'm unable to extract data I need using different methods.

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8")

$body = @"
<s:Envelope xmlns:s=`"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope`" xmlns:a=`"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing`">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand=`"1`">YOUR_URL_HERE</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:MessageID</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand=`"1`">YOUR_URL_HERE</a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <LogOn xmlns=`"http://www.ultipro.com/dataservices/bidata/2`">
            <logOnRequest xmlns:i=`"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`">
                <UserName>USER</UserName>
                <Password>PASS</Password>
                <ClientAccessKey>CACCESSKEY</ClientAccessKey>
                <UserAccessKey>UACCESSKEY</UserAccessKey>
            </logOnRequest>
        </LogOn>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'YOUR_URL_HERE' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body

## This one prints the text that's in the attached screenshot
$response.outerxml

## This code gives me nothing
#$Data = ([xml]$R.RawContent).Envelope.Body.LogOnResponse.LogOnResult.ClientAccessKey.Innertext
#write-host "$Data"

## This code also gives me nothing
#$XPath = '//*[local-name()="Status"]'
#$Nodes = (select-xml -xml $response -XPath $XPath).Nodes
#$Nodes
```

I have tried the code that I have commented out (I got it from google searching).  When I try the code I do not get an error nor do I get results.

What am I doing wrong to extract the data I need?  Thanks.

[EDIT]
I had to remove my altered URL's to get it to post because it marked my question as spam.. :(
I also don't see my screenshot I attached so below is the output from the embedded code that I'm trying to pull the status from:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">YOUR_URL_HERE</a:Action> 
        <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:xxxxxxxx</a:RelatesTo>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <LogOnResponse xmlns="YOUR_URL_HERE">
        <LogOnResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
        <ServiceId>xxxxxxx</ServiceId> 
        <ClientAccessKey>xxxxxxxx</ClientAccessKey> 
        <Token>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Token>
        <Status>Ok</Status>
        <StatusMessage i:nil="true" />
        <InstanceKey>xxxxxxxxxx</InstanceKey>
        </LogOnResult>
        </LogOnResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` outputs the results of parsing the response _body_ - use `Invoke-WebRequest` if you want the raw http response, including headers and status etc.

Comment: Thank you for that.  You got me going.  To get the status after that I added changed this line:
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'YOUR_URL_HERE'.....

To this:
[xml] $response = Invoke-RestMethod 'YOUR_URL_HERE'

I also added this line to pull the status:
$Status = $response.Envelope.Body.LogOnResponse.LogOnResult.Status

That got me going.  Thank you soooo much for your help.

Comment: You have two different Status.  One is the response of the Invoke-RestMethod which would be like "200 OK".  Then you have a second status which is the data inside the XML body.  They are not the same.

Comment: This?
```$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'YOUR_URL_HERE' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
Write-Host "Status: $($response.StatusCode)"
$status = $response.Envelope.Body.LogOnResponse.LogOnResult.Status
Write-Host "Status: $status"```